# Resize string in Swift

Tags: string, swift, notifications, strip

With notifications I can't exceed more than 256 characters. I need to resize a string to be 200 characters maximum.

How could I, for example if I have an string of 210 characters, resize it to 197 and the rest "...". But if I have one string of 100 characters, don't resize it because it fits in the notification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let str = "With notifications I can't exceed more than 256 characters. I need to resize a string to be 200 characters maximum. How could I, for example if I have an string of 210 characters, resize it to 197 and the rest \"...\". But if I have one string of 100 characters, don't resize it because it fits in the notification."

func foo(str: String, width: Int)->String {
    let length = str.characters.count
    if length > width {
        let d = length - width + 3
        let n = d < 0 ? 0 : d
        let head = str.characters.dropLast(n)
        return String(head) + "..."
    }
    return str
}

foo(str, width: 10) // "With no..."
print(foo(str, width: 200))
/*
With notifications I can't exceed more than 256 characters. I need to resize a string to be 200 characters maximum. How could I, for example if I have an string of 210 characters, resize it to 197 ...
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you are OK with adding the ellipsis at the end of your string. In this case, if your string exceeds 200 characters, you need to take a substring of it that goes form the first character (index: 0) to the 197th. Then you concatenate "..." to this substring, and use that in your notification.

There is another possibility that I used in the past: when you generate the notification, you compress your message with come algorithm (I used plain old huffman) and send the compressed version as payload. In your app, you inflate the compressed message and show it, thus practically exceeding the size limit. It goes without saying that this works as long as the compressed version fits in the notification payload. If you can't do that, you'll have to make your message shorter beforehand – either with the method described above, and then send it out in plain text, or you work out the longest you can truncate your message before compressing it so that the deflated version fits inside the payload.

Comment: let's image I have the next string: var data = "This is a string not so long". I need it to be maximum 10 characters and then "..."

How would the code be with substring in Swift?

Comment: If you have a limit of n characters, then you need to check whether your input is lengthier. If so, then take its first n - 3 characters (in this case 7) and add "..." to them to have a 10-charactered string.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this extension to String.  Note that it doesn't do exactly what you want since it uses the unicode ellipsis character instead of 3 periods, but specifying "..." as the second argument would do it:

```
extension String {
    func ellide(length:Int, ellipsis:String = "…") -> String {
        if characters.count > length {
            return self[startIndex..<startIndex.advancedBy(length - ellipsis.characters.count)] + ellipsis
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that this is answering the more literal version of your question about "characters" when you're probably more interested in the # of bytes of the message, which becomes an important distinction if one's dealing with non-ASCII characters.